# kubernetes master api / remote access with kubectl without certificates

Tags: certificate, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to access remotely to kubernetes , but I dont want to use certificates for this

here is the content of my config file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    server: https://172.16.1.9:8443
  name: default-cluster
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    server: https://172.16.1.9:8443
  name: remote-server
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: remote-server
    user: myself
  name: bcmt
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    user: default-admin
  name: default-system
current-context: default-system
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubelet.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubelet-key.pem
- name: myself
  user:
    password: secret
    username: admin
```

when I use only password user name , I am not able to access.

I am not expert in kubernetes,  I guess that I must change something in the remote kubernetes configuration files but I don't know what.

please can you help me for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `kube-apiserver`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-password-file

For all apiserver options see https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/